# Create a new dictionary list from other lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I have a list of repeated words and another list of words not repeated as follows (They are all located in txt files):

```
file1.txt:
listRepeat = ['aaa','aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'bbb', 'ddd']

file2.txt:
listRepeat = ['aaa','eee', 'bbb', 'eee', 'bbb', 'ddd']
```

and the following list that contains the non-repeated elements of the files:

```
listEND = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
```

I want to create a dictionary list as follows:

```
[{'file1.txt':['aaa':2], ['bbb':2], ['ccc':1], ['ddd':2], ['eee':0]}]
[{'file2.txt':['aaa':1], ['bbb':2], ['ccc':0], ['ddd':1], ['eee':2]}]
```

The idea is to populate my dictionary list with the elements of the file lists and say the number of these elements in the list of elements, just like the example above, but I'm not getting the construction of this dictionary right. My code looks like this:

```
for i in listEND:
        newllist.append({file:[i,listRepeat.count(i)]})
```

Where the `newlist` is the dictionary list, where it places the respective `file` as the dictionary key and as items the elements and their respective count in `i`. But the result is this below:

```
{'file1.txt': ['aaa', 2]}
{'file1.txt': ['bbb', 2]}
{'file1.txt': ['ccc', 1]}
...
```

and so on. Does anyone know where is wrong in the code?

Comment: What is your dictionary from and to. Is the final type `List[Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]]`? I think you need to look into exactly what the type you want is. I believe you actually want `Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]`

Comment: Your desired output is mostly nonsensical, as you can't have something like `['aaa':2]` (it's a list with keys and values like a dictionary). I'm not sure we can answer this question if we can't actually tell what the output you want is. You need to figure out what data structure you want at each level of nesting. You could get away with just two levels of dictionaries, but maybe you want lists in there somewhere, but I have no idea where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired output is invalid. It looks like you actually want nested dicts:

```
{'file1.txt': {'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 1, 'ddd': 2, 'eee': 0},
 'file2.txt': {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 0, 'ddd': 1, 'eee': 2}}
```

Making that happen in your code would look like this:

```
...
for i in listEND:
    newdict[file][i] = listRepeat.count(i)
```

But before this step you'll need to define `newdict = {}` and `newdict[file] = {}`.

---

BTW you could consider using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead, but it works a bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
file1 = ['aaa','aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'bbb', 'ddd']
file2 = ['aaa','eee', 'bbb', 'eee', 'bbb', 'ddd']

listEND = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']

file_contents = {"file1.txt":file1, "file2.txt":file2}


new_list = {filename:{x:lst.count(x) for x in listEND} for filename, lst in file_contents.items()}
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
{'file1.txt': {'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 1, 'ddd': 2, 'eee': 0}, 'file2.txt': {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 0, 'ddd': 1, 'eee': 2}}
```